# Increase the number of reviews based on reputation?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review

I really enjoy reviewing posts and providing helpful edits and what not. However, I wish I could review more questions/answers in a given time frame.

What about the possibility of increasing the number of reviews based on either reputation or the number of reviews that you do?

Comment: Expect a very quick [status-declined]. The new review queues have created [a world of trouble](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything), and unfortunately several higher rep users are (still) treating review as a quick way to get some badges. It's unfortunate, but the fact is that a few review monkeys spoiled the fun for everyone...

Comment: also, since this seems to be your first Meta adventure: [voting is (a bit) different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: I see what you are saying. It is sad people would abuse it just to get badges, and thank you for the vote link. I went there when I saw the down votes coming in. Appreciate it!

Comment: Couple of recent examples of dubious approvals (from users with more rep than you): [1](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/827021), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/827006). Fortunately both edits were rejected at the end... It's not so much a problem on the smaller sites of the network, but on SO review is proving to be very problematic.

Comment: Wow... that is crazy!

Comment: I came here to post the same thing. It seems like the best solution to prevent badge abuse is to not have badges for reviews. Then the major incentive becomes the desire to review rather than the desire for badges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The review queue has done a good job of demonstrating that reputation is not a good measurement of the quality of a reviewer you are, so I disagree with the suggestion in principle on that basis.

Also note that the whole point of the limits is because the queues are perpetually sitting at empty due to the fact that there is more demand to review then content that needs reviewing; increasing that limit (even if just for some people) wouldn't create new items to review.  If, at some point in the future, we end up in a position where items are being added to the queues more quickly then they're being removed then we're likely to see the review limits increased.

Comment: Well, this is a good point. I never really thought of it. Well, does not hurt to ask, so thank you for the response. :)

Comment: A counter argument is that if some of us got more than 20 reviews a day, there would also be more reject votes...

Comment: @BoPersson How does it counter which argument?  If it's rep based then it would be effectively giving everyone more votes, if you accept the premise that reputation is unrelated to the quality of the reviewer.  Keep in mind the limit was introduced rather recently; I haven't notice a major change in the quality of the review process as a result.

Comment: It's not about being rep based, it's about limiting everyone to 20 reviews a day. That stops guys like me from rejecting the number of proposed edits we used to reject with the old system. If you look at the stats, you will find lots of people having performed WAY over the 1000 reviews needed for the badges. Why not let us continue with that?

Comment: @BoPersson Imposing a limit does a number of things, including limiting the number of reviews a malicious or unknowledgeable user can perform in a day as well.  Personally, I feel that there are a number of major changes that need to take place for the review system to become functional again, and this particular issue is somewhat low on my list of things that I feel need improvement.